# Error:Artifact 'support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3)' not found. Android studio 1.0.2

Tags: android, jar, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I did a new install of Android Studio 1.0.2. Getting the following error when opening my first existing android project:

Gradle '**MyApplication**' project refresh failed

```
Error:Artifact 'support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3)' not found.
```

Searched in the following locations:   `file:/C:/Users/Ntokozo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v4/21.0.3/support-v4-21.0.3.jar`

And if I navigate to that searched location I found two jar files which are: `support-v4-21.0.3-sources.jar and support-v4-21.0.3-javadoc.jar`

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Gradle file under App folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ntokozo.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Thank you in advance, please bare in mind in responses that I'm a novice and I might not know advanced features.

Comment: Use gradle to import from it's repository, instead of using manually positioned libraries if you don't have to

Comment: Thank you for your response. Would you please tell me how to make gradle import from it's repository.

Comment: add this  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.+'

Comment: I added compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+' and found out that I added it in the top most level gradle.build file and I was suppose to add it to individual's module build file and when I go to individual's module build file it was already there and now I'm stuck I don't know what to do next.

Comment: remove it from the top level gradle file. keep it in the individual module build file. remove it from your libs folder if it is also there. Resync your gradle project, should work.

Answer (score 0):

After re-installing windows OS and a new Android Studio setup the problem disappeared. I don't know what was the problem at first.