# Error:(22,0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

Hi guys I'm having a problem Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()'. Most of the discussions I read suggest that I add compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+' to individual's module build file and in my case the compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+' is already there. If I remove the one I added on the top most level build file I get this error ([Error:Artifact 'support-v4.jar (com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3)' not found. Android studio 1.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28134410/errorartifact-support-v4-jar-com-android-supportsupport-v421-0-3-not-foun?noredirect=1#comment44641164_28134410)).

Please help, here are my gradle files:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}
```

Gradle file under App folder:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ntokozo.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *dependencies block* from the top level build.gradle file.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
}
```

Also update your sdk files.